# How to read DynamoJSON data in S3 to Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

I applied TTL in DynamoDb so that DynamoDB table will not bloat, using this tutorial : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automatically-archive-items-to-s3-using-dynamodb-time-to-live-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-kinesis-firehose/

Now, this tutorial let me save my archived data in S3, in a format of DynamoJSOn. I have a problem reading it in Athena. How to access those data?

TTL data being saved in S3 looks like this:
[image]

folder structure is S3 is this: yyyy/mm/dd.

How to deal with this in Athena?

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem, just saying you have a problem makes it very hard for us to help you. Be specific about error messages, how you set up your tables, etc.

Comment: Okay, editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [AWS Glue Crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-crawlers.html) to infer the schema which can then easily be used by Amazon Athena.

Comment: I tried it but i want to add partitions, how to do that?

Comment: You can manually modify the schema that AWS Glue Crawler has derived from your data, change data types, add partions, etc. You can find more information in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-tables.html#console-tables-details

Comment: That's great. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful.